# Javascript Scope, Start stop buttons using interval

Tags: javascript, scope

I am having an issue with the scope.

I have a stop button that is not working. The start button works great but I can't seem to get the stop button to work and I know it has something to do with scope. I would appreciate any help.

```js
let css = document.querySelector('h3');
let color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
let color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
let color3 = document.querySelector(".color3");
let degree = document.querySelector(".degree");
let body = document.getElementById("gradient");
let deg = document.getElementById("deg");
let random = document.getElementById("random");
let start = document.getElementById("start");
let stop = document.getElementById("stop");


function setGradient() {
  body.style.background =
    "linear-gradient(" +
    degree.value +
    "deg, " +
    color1.value +
    ", " +
    color2.value +
    ", " +
    color3.value +
    ")";

  css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
  deg.textContent = degree.value;
}

function increment() {
  degree.value = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    degree.value = degree.value % 360 + 1;
    setGradient();
    if (degree.value == 359) {
      increment();
    }
  }, 100);
}

start.addEventListener("click", increment);

stop.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval(counter);
});

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
color3.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
degree.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

window.onload = setGradient;
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have an error? Can you add your html?

Comment: provide the HTML part also

Comment: Please add Code Snippet to better understand your task and problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the `counter` variable.

`counter = setInterval(..)`

Comment: When I Set counter to global variable = the timer start automatically without clicking start.

I am thinking I can do that and add the counterInterval() to the window.onload?

Comment: And at a scope that is accessible to both `increment` and the stop callback: `let counter = null`

Comment: @DreamingOfCrypto You're not setting `counter` to a Global variable. You're setting it to the id returned by `setInterval()`.

Comment: @DreamingOfCrypto you should assign it right where it is now on line 31, not outside separately.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the suggestions. I will keep plugging away with them and let you know what I find. Just started learning recently still a little wet behind the ears with javascript.

Comment: https://tranquil-bastion-31753.herokuapp.com/

got it working pretty good. its still a work in progress. I was able to fix it using
let counter;

thanks again for the assistance

Comment: @DreamingOfCrypto nice, i like it. the "hide text" option is kinda irreversible, tho ;)